# How to implement an editable listview in MVVM model?

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm

I have an mvvm application...I need to have an editable listview.
I am binding my observable collection to listview.
How could I track changes of the values in listview ?...I mean if user edit an item...I need to have changed values in my observable collection.

If I use datagrid in WPFToolKit, is it easy ?

Answer (score 0):

In a word, yes.

Take a look at data templates in WPF.  They allow you to define how you want each item in your list (or any control) to appear and behave.  So each item in your listview can one or more editable controls that are bound to each item in your collection (in this case an ObservableCollection).  As you change data in the listview, the bound objects will in your collection will be updated in real time.

This is also possible with a datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this link

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-using-the-listview-part-3-in-place-edit

It is recommended you to use the Datagrid.It already provides the edit mode functionality. You can use a TemplateColumn to provide editing views.

Answer (score 0):

if you have an editable Collection in your viewmodel, just take a datagrid(editable stuff built in). you can create styles or use templates so that the datagrid look the way you want.

> If I use datagrid in WPFToolKit, is it easy ?

yes ;) but if you can, use the .net4 datagrid